# How to avoid FileSystemException (Unable to delete file - Used by other process) when rolling happens using lo4j2?

Tags: java, websphere, log4j2

We hare losing log files when rolling happens using the CronTriggeringPolicy with Log4j2 library and the application is being called at the same time (i used postman to launch 10 calls 5 seconds before the rolling event happen). Is there a way to change the configuration or the way that the loggers are used in the application to make a thread safe rolling while other services are writing in the log file to avoid losing valuable log files in production?

The application is running in IBM WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.14, Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.3, additional technologies/libraries: Java 7, Java EE 6, Log4j2 (v2.11.2).

No frameworks are used, we are using the WebSphere provided implementations.

There are no problems with the permissions on files since the user used to launch the server is the owner of the entire directory and sub directories.

I found that this problem is check when a service (or more services) are writing on the file and the rolling happens. There is a obvious lock of the file when log4j2 tries to move the file. I have read the documentation but i haven't find a clear example to avoid this problem.

This is the websphere entry point class that extends application:

```java
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("")
public NiceServiceApplication extends Application {}
```

Then we have a simple bean to call from the service

```java
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public interface BeanOne {
    public abstract void hello();
    public abstract void setLogger(Logger logger);
}
```

The bean's implementation

```java
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.TransactionManagement;
import javax.ejb.TransactionManagementType;
@Stateless
@Remote(BeanOne.class)
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class BeanOneImpl implements BeanOne {

    private Logger logger;

    public void hello() {
        logger.info("Hello in bean one called :D");
    }

    public void setLogger(Logger logger) {
        if(logger == null) {
            LogManager.getLogger("fallback-logger")
        } else {
            this.logger = logger;
        }
    }
}
```

The Service class

```java
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
@Path("/helloService")
public class NiceService {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("nice-logger");

    @EJB
    private BeanOne bean;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        beanOne.setLogger(logger);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/hello")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response sayHelloToMe() {
        bean.hello();
        return Response.ok().entity("{\"msg\":\"Hello there!\"}").build();
    }
}
```

Lo4j2 configuration used:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO" monitorInterval="30">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">C:\logs</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>

        <!-- Default Console appender -->
        <Console name="console-log" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}:%M - %m%n" />
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="fallback-log-appender"
            fileName="${log-path}/fallback.log"
            filePattern="${log-path}/archive/fallback-%d{yyyyMMddHHmmss}.log.gz">

            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %p %C{1}:%M - %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>

            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" />
                <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0/5 * ? * * *"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>


        <RollingFile name="nice-log-appender"
            fileName="${log-path}/nice-service.log"
            filePattern="${log-path}/archive/nice-service-%d{yyyyMMddHHmmss}.log.gz">

            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %p %C{1}:%M - %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>

            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50 MB" />
                <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0/5 * ? * * *"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>

    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="console-log" />
        </Root>

        <Logger name="fallback-logger" level="trace" additivity="false">
            <Appender-ref ref="fallback-log-appender" level="trace" />
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="nice-logger" level="trace" additivity="false">
            <Appender-ref ref="nice-log-appender" level="trace" />
        </Logger>

    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

The exception im getting is this one from log4j2:

```
[04/07/19 13.35.00:041 CEST] 000000ee SystemOut     O 2019-07-04 13:35:00,041 Log4j2-TF-7-Scheduled-6 ERROR Unable to delete file C:\logs\nice-service.log: java.nio.file.FileSystemException C:\logs\nice-service.log: Impossibile accedere al file. Il file è utilizzato da un altro processo.
```

I expect the gzip log file being move without problems to the archive folder after a rolling event happens.